# How to combine columns in spark as a JSON in Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a variable which is constructed  as follows extracting data using Spark SQL:

```
{
"resourceType" : "Test1",
"count" : 10,
"entry": [{
        "id": "112",
        "gender": "female",
        "birthDate": 1213999
    }, {
        "id": "urn:uuid:002e27cf-3cae-4393-89c5-1b78050d9428",
        "resourceType": "Encounter"
    }]
}
```

I want the output in the following format:

```
    {
    "resourceType" : "Test1",
    "count" : 10,
    "entry" :[
"resource" :{
            "id": "112",
            "gender": "female",
            "birthDate": 1213999
        }, 
"resource" :{
            "id": "urn:uuid:002e27cf-3cae-4393-89c5-1b78050d9428",
            "resourceType": "Encounter"
        }]
    }
```

I am basically new to Scala :), would need help in this.

EDIT: Adding the scala code to create the JSON:

```
val bundle = endresult.groupBy("id").agg(count("*") as "total",collect_list("resource") as "entry").
    withColumn("resourceType", lit("Bundle")).
    drop("id").
    select(to_json(struct("resourceType","entry"))).
    map(row => row.getString(0).
        replace("\"entry\":[\"{", "\"entry\":[{").
        replace("}\"]}","}]}"). // Should be at the end of the string ONLY (we might switch to regex instead
        replace("}\",\"{","},{")
        replace("\\\"", "\"")   
    )
```

Comment: "new to Scala" -- Do you know the Java/Python API to do the same, then? Please add your Spark code

Comment: By the way, the output you've show is not valid JSON

Comment: @cricket_007 Added the Code. And yes its not a valid json. Its more of JSONlines format. :)

Comment: Spark can't output bad JSON. It can output a string just fine, but don't expect to be able to load / parse that back into anything